# ¿Cómo solucionar el desbordamiento del contenido en un div?

Tags: javascript, css

El contenido se sale del `div`, pero el div debería crecer verticalmente y no utilizar scrollbars.

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

```css
div{
background:red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Comment: Y que quieres que pasa? Se corta?

Comment: Se llama desbordamiento. Para ocultar o adaptar el contenido mediante scrollbars juega con la propiedad `overflow`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía el div deberia crecer verticalmente

Comment: y no debo usar scroll

Comment: No utilices `height`, si no `min-height` para darle un alto inicial. Mira mi respuesta.

Comment: @hubman: Los detalles adicionales de la pregunta deben de incluirse en la pregunta misma ya que los comentarios son temporales.

Comment: @hubman Si necesitas que se ajuste el alto de tu contenedor al contenido, debes asignar como valor a la propiedad `height` como `auto;` , mira mi respuesta

Answer (score 13):

Considerando los detalles agregados recientemente a la pregunta, en lugar de usar `overflow` lo que se require es ajustar el tamaño del div para evitar el desbordamiento, pero esto no se puede hacer directamente, lo primero sería "quebrar" la "palabra"

En CSS el atributo para ajustar cadenas de texto es `word-wrap`. En este caso, la cadena no tiene espacios en blanco por lo que se considera que la cadena es una palabra, entonces deberemos usar `word-wrap: word-break`.

Como se indica en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82480/65) de Gustavo García, si se desea que el div crezca verticalmente no deberían usarse un valor fijo para `height`. Existen varias alternativas, una de tantas es usar `height: auto` para ajustar automáticamente el tamaño.

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```css
div {
  background:red;
  width: 100px;
  /* Control de la altura con base en el texto del div*/
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

---

> Respuesta a con base en la revisión 1

Agrega `overflow: hidden;`  Puedes consultar la documentación en [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Ejemplo

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background:red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Dime si esto te sirve amigo

```css
div{
background:red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
margin: 0 auto;
display:block;
overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué has puesto que el ancho sea 100%? Por otro lado no parece una respuesta para el sitio principal, más parece apara el [chat].

Comment: puesto como el original

Comment: Lo del ancho sí. Digamos que además de lo mínimo has incluido varios extras pero no has indicado si hay un motivo.

Comment: Pues solo agregue un margen como de costumbre y mostrar con el estilo bloque lo del div, cosas que me quedaron de antes de tiempos con css, debeo empezar con ciertas cosas de nuevo

Comment: Darle un margen auto y que siempre se muestre

Comment: Con los comentarios agregados a la pregunta pareciera que no le sirvió :)

Comment: dijo que sin scroll por eso es importante no dar respuestas antes de que se hayan aclarado todos los detalles ...

Answer (score 2):

> el div deberia crecer verticalmente

Entonces no le des un alto fijo, al hacer eso estás siendo contraproducente. Si quieres que tenga un alto inicial fijo, utiliza `min-height`:

```css
div{
background:red;
min-height: 100px;
width:100px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la respuesta de [@GustavoGarcía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82480/23233) es la correcta, pero aquí te dejo otra opción con `ellipsis`

```css
div{
background:red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> el div deberia crecer verticalmente

Para eso, debes reemplazar el valor de tu propiedad `height` a la que estas asignandole un alto de 100px, si necesitas que crezca verticalmente, asignale el valor a `auto;` , como resultado el contenedor se adapta a tu contenido.

```css
div{
background:red;
height:auto;
width:100px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una manera sencilla de solucionarlo es adjudicándole al **elemento padre** un `padding: valor;`

Con esto logras hacer que haya cierto espacio  hacia dentro del **contenedor**, y así evitas el desbordamiento de forma ágil.

```
.elementoPadre {
   padding: 10px
}
```

Con esto solucionas el desbordamiento. :D

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funcionó usando el {word-wrap: break-word} en el elemento.
Creo que funciona de esta manera. Normalmente el texto se agrupa en parrafos segun el ancho que le des al elemento contenedor por ejemplo

```
<style type="text/css">
body{width: 750px}
</style>
```

Pero hay algo que al no ser tan comun no es muy tratado y es el caso de palabras largas o varias palabras sin separación. En este caso el html no corta la palabra de manera automatica ni siquiera usando padding o margin por lo que aunque delimitemos el ancho del body en este caso, no hará que la palabra larga se quede dentro del contenedor.
¿Como lo solucionamos?
Usando el {word-wrap: break-word}

Quedaria de esta manera

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
width: 750px ; 
word-wrap: break-word ;
}
</style>
```

Esto forzará la palabra larga a quedarse dentro del contenedor cortandola en partes como estime conveniente.